# PHP + MySQL 'DB connections' slowing server down

Tags: mysql, nginx, pdo, php

I have an ajax-loaded script which runs 2 mysql statements for every single visitor (~100 per second). It's a simple `SELECT` as well as `UPDATE` statement.

For my backend, I'm using AWS RDS.

I noticed my site went down today, I see the logs filled with the following...

**PHP-FPM-5.5 Error log:**

`[11-Jun-2014 17:18:47] WARNING: [pool www] child 12203, script '/var/www/track.php' (request: "GET /track.php") executing too slow (5.282239 sec), logging`

**Slow log**

`script_filename = /var/www/track.php. [0x00007fcf11fda8f8] execute() /var/www/html/track.php:53`

In RDS, my graphs looked like this:

[image]

[image]

You can see the DB connections became very high.

At this point is where I'm a bit confused what to do to prevent this.

I can only assume something 'backed up', maybe the database server took just a fraction of a second too long to respond? Then PHP basically got overloaded because the requests were coming in too fast (too busy 'waiting'), which in turn started to take down my server.

The MySQL statements I have are using `PHP-PDO`. I attempted adding `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 1` to my `new PDO` object, but I have no idea if that would even solve it (or even if it's working or not...).

My goal is to NOT have my server get taken down just because the DB server is slow or unresponsive. I need PHP to be 'smart enough' to not wait for a really long time or get overloaded because MySQL isn't responding fast enough.

All this is pure conjecture though, maybe it wasnt RDS at all, and somehow PHP got backed up? I'm not exactly sure...

Thanks!

Comment: you've to check script for it's problems. also check your tables that used in this script for existence of indexes on fields.
also tune mysql query cache, and try to use memcache to minimize requests to database

Comment: This may be a dumb question but, are you closing the connection in the function that executes the query?

Comment: also use php's mysql persistent connection methods to use mysql connection pool to avoid creating connection everytime

Comment: This looks like one of those vicious cycle overload scenarios where the database server got overloaded momentarily, and responses slowed. As a result the web server underneath php began starting new instances/threads to handle incoming requests instead of reusing the existing pool. So, the database server got a flurry of new connections, and slowed down even more.  There are configuration variables in apache/httpd (and also I am sure in nginx) to keep the pool of active instances / threads from growing too large. You should try tuning that.

Comment: + look at table's engine if it's myisam or innodb cuz myisam engine locks the table everytime you do UPDATE query, but innodb locks only the row where you're making UPDATE.
maybe you better try to use rabbitmq to make update process synchronous to avoid locks.

Comment: @VikingBlooded Not dumb, because I don't think I'm doing it. I add it by doing this after my `execute()`, correct? `$db = null;`

Comment: @Tallboy http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-close.php

Comment: use persistent connection to use connection pool.

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));

Comment: fuk... everything broke when I added ATTR_PERSISTENT. it says this in the error logs. `is blocked because of many connection errors`. How do i unblock it when im using RDS?

Comment: Why does `ATTR_PERSISTENT` keep getting spewed here. There are advantages/disadvantages to using it. As the chart indicates, the connection limit is likely set to 100 so once 100 persistent connections get used at once then this exact issue will occur anyways.

Comment: @Tallboy stop the nginx, stop php-fpm, then stop mysql it will take a time to done with stack of queries then will close connections. then start all of it in reverse order.

Comment: check your table for existence of indexes (add them if not exist), change it's engine to innodb (because of update queries), also give us your track.php script to look at.

Comment: DB is already innoDB, all needed columns have indexes, btw

Comment: So is this more of an Nginx problem or a PHP-FPM (or script...) problem?

Comment: Likely you had some slow-running query which got a table lock and caused connections to stack up.  First of, consider if you you are using an appropriate polling interval for your AJAX calls (if these queries are running repeatedly). Second are these queries all getting common data?  Can you put a cache in front of the RDS instance for the `SELECT` statements?  Do you have the right number of max  connections configured for your traffic load? Do you have the right instance size? There is a lot here that can be explored but without know you use case is hard to answer.

Comment: Its for a split testing tool so unfortunately nothing can be cached. The ajax call is made only once per visitor per page load. In regards to your other question... max connections, I have no idea :/ right instance size... i would assume so. CPU hovers ~20% without going overboard.

Comment: @Tallboy  Do you have slow_query_log turned on?  If so you should be able to go back and see if there was a slow query logged at this point in time which caused connections to be stacked up.  For more on working with MySQL log files in RDS check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MySQL in my most recent project but can't deny the fact that MySQL may have some performance issues.

You could try to send a select request to your database and if it returns true you can then update the row. In this case you'll need two connections per user and per page load. So I will recommend that you use stored procedures which will only require one connection from your script. You could half your connection times with using stored procedures in your scenario.

My second solution is to configure your my.conf according to your required settings. Here is an online tool to help make a suitable configuration https://tools.percona.com/wizard .

MySQL can use up to 40% of system resources for logging so try to limit some logs such as access log, error log, and any additional logs you may be using.

Comment: Note: On the linked website you need to sign up at the end of the wizard to get the generated config. If you aren't comfortable with this you don't have to waste your time with it.